# Pandas keyerror: "None of [Index([..], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" has weird \n character in columns?

Tags: python, pandas

None of [Index(['6aHwr', 'CbKM4', 'PwJxl', 'rWVvg', '98Zw0', '9buXh', 'j2tg7', '9zmpX',\n       'iLeEz', 'qLsIs', 'cBLeM', 'Kawff', 'lsMPq', 'Q30cK', '9xquw', 'Q9hGx',\n       'Yy1lr', 'QcKox', 'xSzpX', 'nU1qr', 'IF0vw', 'k4TZf', 'GqVFO', 'DW8Cg',\n       'DJIFU', '75iYS', 'EFCtT', 'iwyoe', 'SFPf1', 'lLlb9'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Anyone can tell what exactly are the \n characters in the error? I've never seen newlines out of single quotes. I think maybe those are the reason behind this error. If not then please tell what might have caused this.

data.columns gives me

```
Index(['ID', 'ph_no', 'cvv', 'credit_card_number', 'job', 'email', 'url',
       'country', 'name', '6aHwr', 'CbKM4', 'PwJxl', 'rWVvg', '98Zw0', '9buXh',
       'j2tg7', '9zmpX', 'iLeEz', 'qLsIs', 'cBLeM', 'Kawff', 'lsMPq', 'Q30cK',
       '9xquw', 'Q9hGx', 'Yy1lr', 'QcKox', 'xSzpX', 'nU1qr', 'IF0vw', 'k4TZf',
       'GqVFO', 'DW8Cg', 'DJIFU', '75iYS', 'EFCtT', 'iwyoe', 'SFPf1', 'lLlb9',
       'state'],
      dtype='object')
```

Below is the full code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Load your training data
train_data = data  # Assuming data is your loaded training data


# Assuming your numerical features are in columns J to AM, and emotions are in column AN
# Include columns from "J" to "AM" (both inclusive) as features
columns_to_include = list(train_data.columns[9:39])

X_train_numeric = train_data[columns_to_include].values
y_train = list(range(11930))  # Generate a list from 0 to 11999

# Create an imputer instance and fit on X_train_numeric
# Exclude the emotions column from imputation by selecting only numeric columns
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
X_train_numeric_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(X_train_numeric)

print("X_train_numeric_imputed shape:", X_train_numeric_imputed.shape)
print("y_train length:", len(y_train))

# Create and train the Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier
nb_classifier = GaussianNB()
nb_classifier.fit(X_train_numeric_imputed, y_train)

# Load your testing data
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Assuming your numerical features are in columns J to AM in the test data
# Include columns from "J" to "AM" (both inclusive) as features
X_test_numeric = test_data[columns_to_include].values

# Impute missing values in X_test_numeric using the same imputer
X_test_numeric_imputed = imputer.transform(X_test_numeric)

# Make predictions using the trained Naive Bayes model
y_pred = nb_classifier.predict(X_test_numeric_imputed)

# Create a DataFrame with ID and Emotion Predictions
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': test_data['ID'], 'Emotion': y_pred})

# Save predictions to a CSV file for submission
predictions_df.to_csv('predictions.csv', index=False)
```

The full error-

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-5dbc38c247a0> in <cell line: 33>()
     31 # Assuming your numerical features are in columns J to AM in the test data
     32 # Include columns from "J" to "AM" (both inclusive) as features
---> 33 X_test_numeric = test_data[columns_to_include].values
     34 
     35 # Impute missing values in X_test_numeric using the same imputer

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   6128                 if use_interval_msg:
   6129                     key = list(key)
-> 6130                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   6131 
   6132             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['6aHwr', 'CbKM4', 'PwJxl', 'rWVvg', '98Zw0', '9buXh', 'j2tg7', '9zmpX',\n       'iLeEz', 'qLsIs', 'cBLeM', 'Kawff', 'lsMPq', 'Q30cK', '9xquw', 'Q9hGx',\n       'Yy1lr', 'QcKox', 'xSzpX', 'nU1qr', 'IF0vw', 'k4TZf', 'GqVFO', 'DW8Cg',\n       'DJIFU', '75iYS', 'EFCtT', 'iwyoe', 'SFPf1', 'lLlb9'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Update-
Output of print(*columns_to_include, sep='\n') -

```
6aHwr
CbKM4
PwJxl
rWVvg
...
EFCtT
iwyoe
SFPf1
lLlb9
```

Comment: `\n` is just a newline, this has nothing to do with the error. What were you doing exactly?

Comment: It probably is a newline but your question has no context and is not reproducible - you need to provide more details to show how and when you are getting this error.

Comment: Full traceback also could be useful.

Comment: Updated with required information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out test and train csv files had different column names, error resolved by using indices instead of column names.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't explain why you have this error but it seems `columns_to_include` is a list of one element. I suppose the code below should work:

```
#                                       HERE --vvv
X_train_numeric = train_data[columns_to_include[0]].values
```

Are you sure your code is really:

```
columns_to_include = list(train_data.columns[9:39])
```

And not:

```
columns_to_include = [train_data.columns[9:39]]
```

The line above can raised this exception.

Comment: columns_to_include is the same as data.columns I have shown above.
I tried putting index 0 like you said but it didn't change the error.
Also putting list(train_data.columns[9:39]) or [train_data.columns[9:39]] seems to give me same error regardless.

Comment: So, did you try `train_data[columns_to_include[0]].values`?

Comment: I did but that just cuts the array and passes incomplete data...

Comment: What is the output of `print(*columns_to_include, sep='\n')`? (Update your post, don't copy/paste in the comments)

Comment: Oh ok, updated. Also thanks for informing since this is my first query on overflow.

Comment: @SumedhKudale. I really don't understand why you have this error and the output of the previous command. It doesn't match together!!!